# Three level drill down highmap

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps, r-highcharter

I am trying to make multilevel drill down map using highmap, like first map will show all the countries, then clicking any country will drill down to all states in that country, then selecting any state will show all the districts in that.

I have three boundary files, - countries, states and districts. I have never done javascript before, I am from python and R background. However i dont see any such examples except this - https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/map-drilldown . I see this in javascript and also its using only 2 levels. Can anyone help me to use this for 3rd drill down, also i need to join the country/state/district code with my data and show the value in tooltip.

Thanks.

Comment: It works in the same way as for the regular chart. Regular chart: http://jsfiddle.net/wt7pbw7o/, in map you need to define a mapData property: http://fiddle.jshell.net/cpcky41c/

Comment: Thanks, can you add an example map in jsfiddle?

Comment: The second fiddle is a map drilldown.

Comment: Sorry missed it. I can see now. Can you add it as an answer?

Comment: If you can do it in r, that will help me a lot to compare and learn, since I never did js.

Comment: It should be analogous to this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38192825/how-to-make-3-levels-drilldown-plot-in-r-highcharter-possible-other-packages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic usage:

```
    series: [{
  name: 'World',
  data: [{
    'hc-key': 'eu',
    drilldown: 'd1',
    value: 10
  }],
  mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world-continents'],
  joinBy: 'hc-key',
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    format: '{point.name}' + '<br />' + ' {point.value}' + '%'
  }
}],
drilldown: {
  series: [{
    id: 'd1',
    mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/asia'],
    joinBy: 'hc-key',
    click: function() {
      alert('Hello');
    },
    data: [{
      'hc-key': 'ir',
      value: 4,
      drilldown: 'd2'
    }]
  }, {
    id: 'd2',
    mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/europe'],
    joinBy: 'hc-key',
    data: [{
      'hc-key': 'dk',
      value: 4
    }]
  }]
}
```

live example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/jktrefL1/

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Its awesome even though the code cannot be accessible. I have found What I was looking for

Comment: Sir link is broken please do something